# python image recognition find arrows direction

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv, python

trying to figure out the direction of arrows, I got contours and polygons
[example for contours and polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ciiq2.png)

is there any better way than training a model?

tried to find the 2 most longest lines but there are too many points (and not just 6 )

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong way to go. Your problem seems straightforward enough to use [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html). You need your four arrows as templates, and the one with the best match gives you the orientation of the arrow found.

Comment: every arrow i get is little bit different will template matching still work?

Comment: In theory - yes. If the template is slightly different you will likely still get the best match with the correct orientation